# onmouseover-triggered function keeps triggering on mouse over

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I have a function, which is triggered when the mouse goes over a div.

The div contains a link, which is 100% height and width of the containing div. The link contains an image, which the function moves when onmouseover the grandparent (the div).

The function moves the image to the right and then back to the middle.

When I move the mouse over the div the function is triggered but moves the image by only 5px (one loop of the function) and keeps moving it 5px when I move the mouse around - the function is not looping and just loops once on every onmouseover.

```
<div onmouseover="jotArrow(this);" class="latest-entry latest-entry-third" id="news-link-home">

<a class="home-square-link" href="hello.php">Reviews<br/><img src="<?php echo $config['file_path']; ?>/images/squares-arrow.png" width="60px"/></a>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var arrowPos = 0;
var Arrow;

function jotArrow(arrow)
{
    Arrow = arrow.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

    if (arrowPos < 50) {
        arrowPos = arrowPos + 5;
        Arrow.style.left = arrowPos + 'px';
        setTimeout(jotArrow, 10);
    } else {
        jotArrowBack(arrow)
    }
}

function jotArrowBack(arrow)
{
    if (arrowPos > 0) {
        arrowPos = arrowPos - 5;
        Arrow.style.left = arrowPos + 'px';
        setTimeout(jotArrowBack, 10);
    }
}
```

To make sure the code is correct, I modified it a little (from that above) so that it makes an image in a different div move (onmouseover of div1 causes div2 image to move). And it worked fine.

So I am guessing it has something to do with the image being inside the div and the mouse goes over more than one element. But really I don't see why this would be an issue as the function does not care about onmouseout it should just perform it's whole task on the first onmouseover.

I have tried putting the onmouseover attribute on all three elements (the div, the a and the img) separately and all at the same time - same problem.

Comment: By loop I meant the setTimeout - which continuously triggers the function(s) until the desired position

Comment: @BenWin He's using `seTimeout`.

Comment: @Neil Got it ;) Deleted

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to have two problems. As you mentioned, you get multiple mouseover events which confuse the code, but the other problem is that jotArrow fetches the Arrow element every time, and the second time it can't find it because your setTimeout call doesn't pass the parameter. When you switch the code to move another element I assume you just write something like document.getElementById('blah') which picks up the same element each time.

One approach would be to use a helper function initArrow, something like this:

```
function initArrow(arrow)
{
    if (arrowPos == 0) {
        Arrow = arrow.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        jotArrow();
    }
}
```